# discord.py: How to do Bot is missing permissions?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

UPDATE:

I found out the reason why,
here is new working code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        return
```

Hope it works! <3

Answer (score 0):

Use [`discord.Forbidden`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=forbidden#discord.Forbidden)

Try:

```py
if isinstance(error, discord.Forbidden):
     await ctx.send("Bot doesn't have permissions to do this **or** the bot can't do this. Please try again.")
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work though.

Comment: Oh it didnt? you could go to discord.py official server they will help u

Answer (score 0):

You failed in code not

`BotMissingPermissions`

Try this code
`if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):`

or
`if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. The `if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):` doesn't work. If user will use wrong command which in bot doesn't exist, it will give an error. 

The `if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):` code doesn't work.